# Does the Logic App Service Bus connector support paired namespaces?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-queues

Does the Logic App Service Bus connector support paired namespaces?

I've read through the notes on [Service Bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-servicebus), and can't see anything on paired namespaces

And especially the siphoning process for pulling back messages from the [secondary backlog queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-paired-namespaces)

Comment: Based on my experience, it is not supported in the Logic App, as I can't find a way to config another namespaces for a single Logic App. If you have any ideas, please give your [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) to azure team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now (15th April 2017), this is not supported in the current SB connector.

You can share the idea [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback)

Yes, @Tom Sun - MSFT is right.